# Why do I have to cd out of a deleted directory?

Tags: shell, command-line, directory, cd-command

On my server I have a directory structure looking something like this:

```
/myproject/code
```

I normally have an ssh connection to the server and 'stand' in that directory:

```
root@machine:/myproject/code#
```

When I deploy a new version of my code, the code directory is removed so I'm left with:

```
root@machine:/myproject/code# ./run
-bash: ./run: No such file or directory
```

And the only solution I've found is to cd out and back in:

```
root@machine:/myproject/code# cd ../code
root@machine:/myproject/code# ./run
Running...
```

Can I avoid this? It's a somewhat strange behavior. If you have a nice explanation why this happens I would appreciate it.

Comment: Have you thought about removing the files in your code directory and not the code directory itself?

Comment: we can't really tell, because it could just be because your script uses relative path.
you try to put a bit more information in here. Also your title does not match with your question

Comment: It's just that my deploy script does "rm -fr code && tar xf code.tar" so that I don't get any leftovers from the last version. I could ofcourse change that. But I'm very curious about the result, and why this happens.

Comment: You are mistaken that the newly created directory `run` is the same as the old directory. It only has the same name and parent directory. Compare this to you shredding your old car and buying a new car of the exact same color and model: You would not want to sit in the car being shredded and hope you end up on the new one unharmed, would you?

Comment: Anthon: What I assume is that the path is what identifies the directory. To me the "cd ../code" is a noop. I'm very interested into hearing why it isn't.

Comment: @MarkusJohansson `cd ../code` is not a noop. `..` is a shortcut for the parent of the path that you have, or used to have. If your current directory is deleted the parent path might still exist, and in this case be reachable by evaluating `..`. In that directory a search is done for a directory with name 'code'.

Comment: @MarkusJohansson Instead of removing and tarring code, I would highly recommend to use any version control tool available. Far more easy to share update (just push or pull) and less options to accidentally delete the wrong files. And you keep older version by default.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> To me the "cd ../code" is a noop. I'm very interested into hearing why it isn't.

Because files and directories are fundamentally [filesystem inodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode), not names -- this is perhaps an implementation detail specific to the filesystem type, but it is true for all the ext systems, so I'll stick to it here.

When a *new* directory `code` is created, it is associated with a new inode, and that's where it is.  There is no record kept of previously deleted files and directories, so there is no means by which the system could check what inode it used to occupy and perhaps shuffle things around so that it is the same again; such a system would quickly become unworkable, and in any case, it is probably no guarantee that you would be back there again -- that would be sort of undesirable, since it means you could also accidentally end up somewhere else if a directory is created that takes your (currently unused) inode.

I'm not sure if this last possibility exists, or if the inode of the deleted directory currently assigned to your present working directory is tracked so that nothing will be assigned to it for the duration, etc.

Comment: This is the real answer here.

Answer (score 14):

Your shell *doesn't* every time do a `cd` to the path that it was in during the last command, before executing the next command.

You deleted the current directory and created a directory with the same name, which is not the same directory, just something with the same name/path.

File browsers like Nautilus and Windows Explorer normally "go up" the directory tree if a directory gets deleted on a local file system. However this is not always true for networked file systems, in that case sometimes the deletion does not get noticed and the reappearance could have you ending up in the new directory.

A shell could `cd` into the current directory before executing the next command, I am not aware of any that do (or can be configured to do so).

Comment: Fol illustration - in theory, there could even exist a file system where the old, deleted (or rather unlinked) directory still exists and is readable, while the new one is already in use too. That would not be useful in practice with directories, but with files, it is pretty common.

Answer (score 4):

On most UNIX-like systems, the "current directory" for a process is stored in the kernel as a file descriptor pointing to that directory. The kernel doesn't actually store the path of the current directory: that information is tracked by your shell.

A filesystem object (file *or* directory) is only destroyed for good when all filesystem links to it are gone, *and* there are no file descriptors pointing to that object.

So, if a directory is removed while there's still a process holding it as its current working directory, the process's `cwd` will keep the directory from being truly deleted. The filesystem links that anchor the directory (its entry in the parent directory, and all of its contents) will be gone, but the directory itself will continue to exist as a sort of "zombie". Meanwhile, you can create a brand new directory at the same location as the old one, which is a completely different filesystem object but which shares the same path.

Thus, when you do `cd ../code` (or, on many shells, `cd .`), you are actually traversing the filesystem hierarchy and going to the *new* directory that resides at the old address.

By analogy, removing a directory would be like forcefully moving a house to the garbage dump (breaking ties to the previous address). If there was still someone living there (using it as their `cwd`), they'd have to leave before the house could be razed. In the meantime, a brand-new house could be built at the old address.

Answer (score 0):

@Anthon cleared reasons, why it happens
As solution you may use *alias*, as example:

```
alias 1234='PROJECT=`pwd`; cd $PROJECT ; ./run'
```

aliases for bash are keept in ~/.bashrc

Answer (score 0):

Confirming The current working directory IS based on the inode number, not what you looked up to get there. Since you are using bash, you can use $PWD as follows to cd to the new directory of the same name:

cd $PWD

To illustrate, I made a dummy deploy command:

```
set -x
cd ~/tmp
rm -rf code
mkdir code
echo echo hello from $* > code/run
chmod +x code/run
```

Created the first deployment, cd'd to code and then checked contents with `ls -lai` so you can see the inodes:

```
ianh@abe:~/tmp$ ./,deploy first
++ cd /home/ianh/tmp
++ rm -rf code
++ mkdir code
++ echo echo hello from first
++ chmod +x code/run
ianh@abe:~/tmp$ cd code
ianh@abe:~/tmp/code$ ls -lai
total 12
22945913 drwxr-xr-x  2 ianh ianh 4096 Apr  9 23:12 .
22937618 drwxrwxr-x 14 ianh ianh 4096 Apr  9 23:12 ..
22939455 -rwxr-xr-x  1 ianh ianh   22 Apr  9 23:12 run
```

Now run the 2nd deploy

```
ianh@abe:~/tmp/code$ ../,deploy 2nd
++ cd /home/ianh/tmp
++ rm -rf code
++ mkdir code
++ echo echo hello from 2nd
++ chmod +x code/run
```

And check the directory contents ... now there isn't anything in the directory! not even '.' and '..'! From this you can see that bash is not using the '..' directory entry when you run `cd ..` since '..' no longer exists - I presume its part of its $PWD handling. Some other/older shell's don't handle `cd ..` in this situation, you have to cd to an absolute path first.

```
ianh@abe:~/tmp/code$ ls -lai
total 0
```

Cd to `$PWD` and try again:

```
ianh@abe:~/tmp/code$ cd $PWD
ianh@abe:~/tmp/code$ ls -lai
total 12
22945914 drwxr-xr-x  2 ianh ianh 4096 Apr  9 23:12 .
22937618 drwxrwxr-x 14 ianh ianh 4096 Apr  9 23:12 ..
22939455 -rwxr-xr-x  1 ianh ianh   20 Apr  9 23:12 run
ianh@abe:~/tmp/code$ ./run
hello from 2nd
```

Note how the inode for the current directory (.) changed?

If your deploy script moved the old directory to some other name, eg `mv code code.$$` in the ,deploy script above, then `./run` would work, **but** until you use `cd $PWD` you would be running the **old** code, not the new.

```
ianh@abe:~/tmp/code$ ./run
hello from 2nd
ianh@abe:~/tmp/code$ ../,deploy 3rd
++ cd /home/ianh/tmp
++ '[' -d code ']'
++ mv code code.9629
++ mkdir code
++ echo echo hello from 3rd
++ chmod +x code/run
ianh@abe:~/tmp/code$ ./run
hello from 2nd
ianh@abe:~/tmp/code$ cd $PWD
ianh@abe:~/tmp/code$ ./run
hello from 3rd
```

Deploying using capistrano has the same issue (They have a symlink from the name current to the current release), so I use aliases to cd to the production/staging areas as well as set RAIL_ENV appropriately:

```
alias cdp='export RAILS_ENV=production; echo RAILS_ENV=$RAILS_ENV ; cd /var/www/www.example.com/current'
alias cds='export RAILS_ENV=staging; echo RAILS_ENV=$RAILS_ENV ; cd /var/www/staging.example.com/current'
```

Answer (score 0):

> What I assume is that the path is what identifies the directory.

The path to something is how you get there, not the thing itself.  The path to your bed may be through your room, but once you are in bed, if someone picks it up and carries it outside, you are no longer in your room.

Answer (score 0):

<sup>Not a self-contained answer, but I have an additional point, which the commenting margin was too small to contain.</sup>

To get a better feel for the idea that a directory in the relevant file systems is more than just a path, try moving another process's current working directory: in one shell, start an interactive Python session:

```
$ python
>> import os
>> os.getcwd()
'/home/you/hocus'
```

Then, go to another shell and move that directory:

```
$ cd /home/you
$ mv hocus pocus
```

Back to the original one:

```
$ python
>> import os
>> os.getcwd()
'/home/you/hocus'
>> os.getcwd()
'/home/you/pocus'
```