# Strange error (?) when I run `man` command from a folder that no longer exists

Tags: command-line, error-handling

Let's have a look at the followings:

```
radu@Radu:~$ mkdir test
radu@Radu:~$ cd test
radu@Radu:~/test$ rmdir ~/test
radu@Radu:~/test$ man ls
man: can't change directory to '': No such file or directory
```

Normally, I would say that the last line from the previous output from my terminal is an error. But how can I understand it? And why does this appear only in the case of `man` command (as far as I know; even `pwd` or `ls` does not have any problem)?

Furthermore, let's see again:

```
radu@Radu:~/test$ man ls
man: can't change directory to '': No such file or directory
radu@Radu:~/test$ echo $?
0
```

What? It was a success (see the output of `man man |& grep -A 1 '^EXIT STATUS$'`)?

#### Another version of man

When attempted with another version of `man` the same thing works.

```
$ mkdir mantst
$ cd mantst/
$ man ls            <--- works
$ rmdir ../mantst/
$ man ls            <--- works
$ man --version
man 2.6.3
```

Comment: Your computer is attacked by aliens :D The same commands that you had mentioned perfectly fine for me.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028874/what-happens-to-an-open-file-handler-on-linux-if-the-pointed-file-gets-moved-de) might also help.  That said this is a _FAQ_ of sorts.

Comment: @devnull I did not asked [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/123717/37944) an I can't find an answer there...

Comment: @Ramesh Ubuntu 14.04...

Comment: @RaduRădeanu Depends what you consider as _answer_.  Moreover, a question is not only duplicate when asked by the same person.

Comment: @devnull Believe me, I know what a duplicate is, and please read more closer these 2 Q to understand what  I mean.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu (1) As commented in the other answer, the problem cannot be reproduced.  (2) You claim that you're asking multiple questions in the same post.  (3) This is specifically about Ubuntu.  You might be better off posting this at AskUbuntu.

Comment: @devnull Offf... Maybe **that** problem cannot be reproduced for some people (but in the end has an accepted answer), and **this** problem probably cannot be reproduced by you. It's specifically about Ubuntu?!? No, it's all about `man 2.6.7.1`. I use multiple questions?!? No, I want to understand if `man: can't change directory to '': No such file or directory` is an error or not.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu Stop howling.  I can read text in normal typeface.

Comment: @devnull why is this a dupe? The OP here is asking about a very specific case that's not addressed in the dupe. Their `man` seems to behave differently.

Comment: @terdon I assume that a question isn't closed as duplicate with 1 vote.  If you don't feel this is a duplicate, feel free...

Comment: @devnull and I have, I only singled you out because you happened to have commented. I was wondering if I'd missed something since this really does not seem like a dupe to me.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu - in everyone elses defense this did appear to be a duplicate. We're reopening it now thanks to terdon.

Comment: Try running both versions with `strace`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between `man` and other commands like `ls` is that latter ones (those not complaining about non-existent directory) don't try to explicitly *change* there but already *stay* there.  Man also does, but it additionally tries to explicitly change there, too.

UNIX directories (as files) aren't deleted immediately when you call `unlink(2)` or `rmdir(2)` on them, but just their directory entry in the parent directory is removed.  The directory/file stays as long as there are processes referencing them.  As soon as the last reference is gone, the kernel effectively removes the blocks belonging to the files/directories.

For this cause there is no error when you call `ls` in a directory not existing anymore, since your shell is still there (it references the directory as its current directory) and `ls` started from there just inherits this property.  But since `man` explicitly tries to `chdir(2)` there, thus to a directory *entry* that doesn't exist anymore, it bails out.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. But what can you say about th exit status which is 0 (success) in this case?

Comment: That's simply weird. ;)  Could you tell me which version of `man` you're using?

Comment: `man 2.6.7.1`...

Comment: Hm, unclear.  tl;dr… The source code is a bit more complicated than I thought, so I'll have to owe you this exact answer. :(

Comment: Damn, then my first thought was right after all (I guess).  Do you something fancy™ with your prompt or similar?  Is pre_cmd a defined function?  Some shell magic happening between program exit and printing of the prompt would clearly explain the 0 exit status.

Comment: I think that I will report a bug on Launchpad in this sense....